# meteor allow Collection.insert only if specific Session/Sessions are not false

Tags: javascript, session, collections, meteor

i got those Sessions:

```
Session.set("group_name",false);
Session.set("group_date",false);
Session.set("group_friends",false);
Session.set("group_location",false);
Session.set("group_rules",false);
Session.set("group_desc",false);
Session.set("group_save",false);
```

i want the user to be able to insert only if all Sessions have value that is not false, and that value is valid,
for example group name cannot be "123" or "  a  " ( i know i can do it using regexp but i prefer doing it using meteor check and match).

doing:

```
       if(Session.get("group_date") != false && Session.get("group_friends") != false && ...){
CollectionName.insert({name:Session.get("group_name")},...)
    }
```

seems tedious and wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create just one Session var instead of 7:

```
Session.set("group", {
    name: false,
    date: false
    //etc...
})
```

Then if you need to update any of these:

```
var group = Session.get("group");
group.name = "Bob";
Session.set("group", group);
```

Now inside your method you can either iterate over the properties using `for(key in Session.get("group"))` or just use Underscore which comes built-in with Meteor:

```
var group = Session.get("group");
if(_.all(group, function(val) { return !!val; }){ //checks that all properties of group are not false
    CollectionName.insert({name:Session.get("group_name")},...)
}
```

Obviously if you need to apply more complex validation than simply checking if the value is not false, then you have to do it on per-datafield basis, there is absolutely no other way. E.g.:

```
var group = Session.get("group");

check(group, validateGroup);

CollectionName.insert({name:Session.get("group_name")},...)

function validateGroup(group){
    check(group, {
        name: String,
        date: Date
        //etc.
    }

    if(group.name.length < 3 || group.name == "whatever else you need to compare it to"){
    return false;
}
 //further validation...
```

More on that here: http://docs.meteor.com/#matchpatterns

Comment: at first i thought to have a Session with 7 properties (key value pairs), but doing 7 of those seems more suitable. im not so familiar with underscore so i think ill borrow your _.all example. also  i find the validation system that ships with meteor almost useless unfortunately

Comment: Yeah, it's possible that 7 separate session vars could be more suitable, in which case you'd have to do pretty much what you posted in your question (the "tedious and wrong" block). Why do you think Meteor's validation is useless? Never had to use it myself as it's a fairly new addition, but it looks quite straight-forward and even neat..

Comment: i just wish that the validation system will a have more methods for real validation, because it is very common for example to validate an email a six figure password and so on and not a general things like string boolean and so on.